# How to pause/play a sketch in processing with the same button?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to implement a pause/play for a sketch with the same key, for example if I press p the sketch should stop and if I press p again, the sketch should start again. So far I used the noLoop()/loop() to do this but with two different keys (p for pause, r for start). It does work if I use keyPressed() and keyReleased() but this means to hold down the key but this doesn't answer my question. Also in the pause mode I used redraw() for a single step while noLoop() and works good.
Here is some code I tried so far with two different keys:

```java
public void draw(){
    background(random(255));
}

public void keyPressed(){
    if ( key == 'p' )
        noLoop();
    if ( key == 'r' )
        loop();
    if ( key == 's' )
        redraw();
}
```

And this is the code with the same key:

```java
public void draw(){
    background(random(255));
}

public void keyPressed(){
    if ( key == 'p' )
        noLoop();
    if ( key == 'p' )
        loop();
    if ( key == 's' )
        redraw();
}
```

In this case when I press key it doesn't have any effect.
And the last one I tried is this:

```java
public void draw(){
    background(random(255));
}
public void keyPressed(){
    if ( key == 'p' )
        noLoop();
    else
        loop();
    if ( key == 's' )
        redraw();
}
```

In this case when I press 'p' it stops the sketch but is doesn't play again. Because of the 'else' it plays again when I press any key including 's' which suppose to be just for a single step.
Any help is more than welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and paste to run ourselves. The code you've posted is almost a MCVE, but please include a `draw()` function so we can see exactly the same thing as you.

Here's a simple MCVE that demonstrates the problem you're having:

```java
void draw() {
  background(random(255));
}

public void keyPressed() {

  if ( key == 'p' ) {
    noLoop();
  }
  if ( key == 'p' ) {
    loop();
  }
}
```

This code will show a randomly flashing background. If you press the `P` key, you're expecting it to pause, but it just keeps flashing.

You need to get into the habit of stepping through your code to understand exactly what it's doing. Read through the `keyPressed()` function line by line, and imagine what the code will do when you press the `P` key.

The first `if` statement checks whether the key is `P`, and since it is, it calls the `noLoop()` function. Then the second `if` statement checks whether they key is `P`, and since it is, it calls the `loop()` function. This reverses the call to `noLoop()` we just made, which makes it appear as though nothing happens.

You need to track the **state** of your sketch. In your case, you need to track whether the sketch is currently paused. You could use a single `boolean` variable for this. Then use that variable to make sure you do the right thing when the `P` key is pressed. Something like this:

```java
boolean paused = false;

void draw() {
  background(random(255));
}

public void keyPressed() {

  if ( key == 'p' ) {

    paused = !paused;

    if (paused) {
      noLoop();
    } else {
      loop();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated. This was my first question here and I didn't know about MCVE. I edited the post and I think is the way you sugested. About the code now it is working exactly how I need it and I'll keep in mind your recommendation to get the habit of stepping through the code.